# word count by 'wc' command is not working correctly

Tags: java, shell, filewriter

I wrote a large number of word in a text delimited by tab. After then when when I count number of words by `wc -w filename.txt` command the number of word is not correct. Here is my code for writing words in the file-

```
File file=new File("/Users/mainulquraishi/Documents/sentiment_directory_new/1999/Books/lemmas/lemma.txt");
FileWriter write = new FileWriter(file, false);
String line=null;
for (int i=0;i<wordList.size();i++){
  if(line==null)
    line=(String) wordList.get(i);
  else
    line=line+"\t"+wordList.get(i);
}
write.write(line);
write.close();
```

For example, actually i wrote 3575 words but the word count shows 3932 word.
Any idea why?

Comment: I suggest you print out the `wordList.size()`

Comment: Are you sure each 'word' entry in the list is strictly ONE word? Are there no entries with multiple words (such as wordList.get(0).equals("abc def"))?

Comment: My guess is that some of your words contain spaces. The first thing you should try to do is reproduce this with a very small number of words - fewer than 10. Then you can show us a short but complete program demonstrating the problem... if you still need to.

Comment: Also, that null case looks off... If you have a single null, you erase all the previous words...

Comment: i was trying to detect whether there is space or not by  lemma.contains(" ") function and it didn't detect any space. sorry for my late response. but i need the solution badly